# How do I write the same shell script in Python?

Tags: python, shell, eval

I am new to Python. I am attempting to convert my shell script to Python language. I have a piece of code as below in shell, to be converted to Python.

Shell code I wrote:

```
f_consolidate_output_test()
{
 v_index=$2
 eval "v_$1_list[${v_index}]"=${v_line}
 #echo "Pass list[${v_index}] : ${v_pass_list[${v_index}]}";
 #echo "Fail list[${v_index}] : ${v_fail_list[${v_index}]}";
}
```

This function has two arguments argument1 is a string it has values either pass or fail and second argument is index number.

If I receive first argument value as "pass", I build an array as "v_pass_list", if I receive value as "fail" I build an array with name v_fail_list using the index received as second argument.

This same thing I need in Python.

Please help me on this.

Thank you so much in advance.

Regards,
Macharla Ramesh Kumar

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For "variable variables" (`v_$1_list`), you would use a dict that maps the `$1` to something else.

```
v_lists = {"pass": {}, "fail": {}}

def f_consolidate_output_test(flag, v_index, v_line):
    v_lists[flag][v_index] = v_line
```

This will happily crash if `flag` is not `"pass"` or `"fail"`.